# How to check if an update is available - Swift 4.2 iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, ios12

Good morning, I want to know how can I check if an update is available from getting new updates when I commit on my Github then a popup appears and ask that an update is available on the main windows at opening my app.

Thank you warmly for helping,

Louis.

EDIT: It's for private purposes not for a public release to the App Store

Answer (score 1):

The Siren framework compares the app version it sees on iTunes App Store with the version number of the currently running app.  If the App Store has a higher version, Siren can show an alert.

The Siren README contains all the code snippets you need.

Of course pushing to GitHub won't work because your new app version must be pushed to Apple and reviewed by them.

Comment: I don't want to release my app to the App Store just for private purposes, it's a private project I just want to compare the version of the project on the GitHub and on my App and shows a popup when GitHub is upper

Comment: @LouisLegout I didn't get that from your question. Then you need to inject the latest commit hash of your app code as a string to your code. You can do this for example using the `-D` C compiler option: `-Dcommit=3af43d23ea90cd...`. Get the commit hash using a piece of shell script and add that to your app build process. ...